# Chrome auto adding height to body element

Tags: html, css, ruby, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

Chrome is appending a height to my  element on all of the pages in my site.  It does not do this in Firefox.  Regardless of the height of the page, it is always adding height: 958px to the body element.  This is how the chrome browser is reading it:

```
<body class="other" style="height: 958px">
```

In Firefox, however, it does not append the height to the body and it just reads:

```
<body class="other">
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

body.other {
  background-image: url( "/assets/bg_grey_noise_more.png" );
}
```

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap for my UI framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's being added by the hideAddressBar() function.